# Meaning of negative angle

Tags: trigonometry, angle

If I consider $\alpha=-\frac{\pi}{3}$ this is exactly equal to $2\pi-\frac{\pi}{3}$?
So the consider blu angle is equal to consider the red one?[image]

Comment: I would not say $-\frac\pi3=2\pi-\frac\pi3$, but I would say $\cos(-\frac\pi3)=\cos(2\pi-\frac\pi3)$ (and same with $\sin$ in place of $\cos$)

Comment: What is the meaning of a negative angle so?

Comment: As you ask the question, the answer is simply NO because obviously $-\dfrac{\pi}{3}\ne2\pi-\dfrac{\pi}{3}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *If we are talking about your special question:*

When considering angles on the circle, you should see them modulo $2\pi$.
Let $\alpha = -\frac{\pi}{3} $ and $\beta = 2\pi - \frac{\pi}{3}$. Since $\alpha \equiv \beta \pmod {2\pi}$ they will coincide on the circle.

---

- *If we are talking about the meaning of the negative angle in general:*

These all are just an agreement of mathematicians (plus everyone else working in related fields).

For convenience, we say *"rotate $-30^\circ$"* instead of saying *"rotate $30^\circ$ clockwise"* or *"rotate $300^\circ$"*

So, whenever you see a negative angle, you should think of its direction.